# Use of a global variable ('submission counter')

Tags: rules

I'm trying to construct a registration form (of a node) wich stores serial (ascending) values in a hidden field.
The form is open to unregistered users.
I made it with rules and variable (every time a node of type xxx is saved, the global variable is +=1 and stored in the correct field), but... If two nodes are submitted at the same time, this variable can be dupplicated.
Any ideas on how avoid this behaviour?
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure how granular the dp timestamp actually is but I suppose it's highly unlikely that two nodes are submitted at the exact same time / timestamp.

Comment: Thank you... How can I verify / change the dp timestamp?

Comment: Even thought two nodes are submitted exactly the same time, they will be in a line to be processed. So there won't be one id for both.

Comment: Unfortunately, it happends... I also thought that there was a queue, but it's not like that, if the node are submitted at the same hour, minute, and second, the rule can be misconfused. 
I tried "before saving a content" and also "after".
Also a function like hook_node_presave() gives me same problem if the nodes are processed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend implementing the [Serial Module:](https://www.drupal.org/project/serial)

> This module provides an auto-increment (serial) field.
>
> Unlike Drupal's built-in auto-increment node ID, which is global and
>   shared by nodes belonging to all content types, serial fields are
>   managed per content type (D6) / entity (D7). For example, the serial
>   field of an Invoice instance will generate a unique sequential number
>   (starting at 1, then 2, etc.) exclusively for Invoice instances.
>
> The allocation of serial numbers by this module is atomic. In other
>   words, the serial values are unique even when multiple instances of
>   the same content type / entity are created simultaneously.